# Connect Android to PC with TightVNC and AndroidVNC

Tags: vnc, android, tightvnc

I want to connect my Galaxy S2 to my PC using AndroidVNC (for the Android) and TightVNC (for the PC), or any other combination of software to VNC. So far I have managed to port forward ports 5500, 5800, and 5900 on my machine and open my firewall to TightVNC (it did it by default on installation). But whenever I try to login to my PC from my phone, it always times out on `establishing handshake`. I double checked all the steps (including making sure my IP was correct and my ports are open with http://www.canyouseeme.org/). Any ideas what I could try next?

Comment: Have you tested it with something other than your phone from the outside?

Comment: Also, do you have wifi so you can confirm that it works within your network?

Comment: Paul, I have tried to get into my computer from my work computer and that didn't work, but I heard that offices can block such outgoing connections so I can't take that to mean anything. Also I tried to get in from both my machine and another machine on my home network and those got through just fine. I was quite amused by the cascading window effect :). PS, no wifi unfortunately :(

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas as to what else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

What display number are you using for TightVNC?  I was having the same problems and figured out that I needed to add the display number to the default port number.  So, using display 1, I had to connect to Port 5901.

Once I did that androidVNC connected fine.